# ansible list files in a directory

Tags: list, ansible

Can somone explain to me why this doesn't work? I want to get a list of files within a directory and use it as an input for the loop.

```
---

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      capabilities: []

  - name: find CE_Base capabilities
    find:
      paths: /opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/capabilities/CE_BASE
      patterns: '*.yml'
    register: CE_BASE_capabilities

  - name: debug_files
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.path }}"
    with_items: "{{ CE_BASE_capabilities.files }}"

  - set_fact:
      thispath: "{{ item.path }}"
      capabilities: "{{ capabilities + [ thispath ] }}"
    with_items: "{{ CE_BASE_capabilities.files }}"

  - name: Include CE_BASE
    include_tasks: /opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/process_capabilities_CE_BASE.yml
    loop: "{{ capabilities }}"
```

Edit:
This code is attempting to create a list called capabilties, which contatins a list of files in a particular directory.

When i ran this code without trying to get the files automatically, it looked like this.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    CE_BASE_capabilities:
      - '/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/capabilities/CE_BASE/CE_BASE_1.yml'
      - '/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/capabilities/CE_BASE/CE_BASE_2.yml'

  - name: Include CE_BASE
    include_tasks: /opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/process_capabilities_CE_BASE.yml
    loop: "{{ CE_BASE_capabilities }}"
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: The set fact fails on the second file. It doesn't seem to produce the list properly.

Comment: What are the expected and actual output?

Comment: So, the expected output is that i will get a list called capabilities. This contains each of the filepaths gathered from the find. What i'm actually getting is the first iteration of the with_items seems to succeed, but the second iteration has this error: {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ capabilities + [ thispath ] }}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"}

Comment: Don't spread the needed info to answer your question over comments. Edit your question instead and add it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define `thispath` as a fact but as a local `vars` in the `set_fact` task. Beside that, you don't need to init `capabilities` if you use the `default` filter.

```yaml
  - vars:
      thispath: "{{ item.path }}"
    set_fact:
      capabilities: "{{ capabilities | default([]) + [ thispath ] }}"
    with_items: "{{ CE_BASE_capabilities.files }}"
```

Moreover, you don't even need to loop. You can extract the info directly from the existing result:

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      capabilities: "{{ CE_BASE_capabilities.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```